# How to increment a variable in php using the date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm developing a page in which I want to record events using a date. e.g. If we are in March 2016, the value the code has to generate for the first event is 1_03_2016, then if there is another event to happen in March the value will be 2_03_2016, then if there is another event to happen in March again the value will be 3_03_2016 and so on and so on.

I have done the following:

```
$date= date('Y-m-d');


$time=strtotime($date);
$month=date("m",$time);
$year=date("Y",$time);

$zuva="";
$previous=0;
$sql = "select * from offense order by id desc limit 1";
$query_result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)){

$previous = $row['previous'];
$zuva=$row['date'];
}
$time1=strtotime($zuva);
$month1=date("m",$time1);
$year1=date("Y",$time1);
if($month === $month1){


$previous++;
$casenumber = $previous."_".$month."_".$year;


}   elseif($date != $zuva){
    //$date= date('Y-m-d');
    $previous=0;
    $previous++;

$casenumber = $previous."_".$month."_".$year;
    }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($query_result)==0){
    $previous=0;
    $previous++;

    $casenumber = $previous."_".$month."_".$year;

    }
$_SESSION['casenum']=$casenumber;
$_SESSION['previous']=$previous;

}
```

So i want the variable $casenumber to increment for every entry I insert into the database. Here is the screen of the table I want to insert into:
[image]

Here is the query Im using to insert:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `complaint_search` VALUES('','$identification_number','$casenumber')";
            $query_run2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

After adding apokryfos code:

[image: after adding apokryfos code]

Comment: Just as an aside, this `2_03_2016` looks like the 2nd March 2016 to me. Might not be an issue but if I looked at these values in the database I would think you were talking about d/m/y instead of <number of events>/m/y

Comment: Also, sorting  the events in  date/time order would be 'not as easy as it could be'? If you have stored the date/time as a separate attribute in the `event` then I really would suggest that you a different format for the id? The format you have specified is 'not as useful as it could be'?

Comment: I'm with @RyanVincent - just add a 'counter' integer and then your queries will use ORDER BY your_date_var, icount. Much easier and cleaner. Good luck.

Comment: Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` commands. `mysql_*` is deprecated...

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a table with a list of `events` and their `dates`, and then from that table create a `view` which gives the amount of events in a given month. You could then create a PHP function to generate that view for a given month/year.

Comment: @Henders `2_03_2016` will be the second event that would have occurred in March, it will then be difficult if i have more than one event in the same day, so that will be <incrementing_number_of_events>/m/y

Comment: @RyanVincent ok, I will try separating the date/time, and yes, I will improve everything in the system including `mysql_*` I just need to have this part figured out,then i actually have to bootstrap the system too...@Warl0ck thanks

Comment: @Pigeon Im getting the first part where you saying I should separate the events and dates but the thing is I want the first number to be able to increment as events are being added and picking up the month and year

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your code to something like:

```
<?php

function getNextCaseNumberId() {
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $month = date("m", $time);
    $year = date("Y", $time);
    $sql = "select * from `complaint_search` WHERE casenumber LIKE '%_{$month}_{$year}' order by cs_id desc limit 1"; //Assuming your CS_ID is autoincrement
    $query_result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($query_result) == 0) {
        return "1_{$month}_{$year}";
    } else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);        
        $lastId=explode("_",$row["casenumber"])[0];
        return ($lastId+1)."_".$month."_".$year; //Missed an underscore here
    }
}
```

Then you insert the new complaint like:

```
// Probably best to lock the complaint_search table here
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `complaint_search` VALUES('','$identification_number','".getNextCaseNumberId()."')";        
$query_run2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
//But don't forget to unlock it here
```

Comment: This is exactly what Im looking for...let try to implement it

Comment: After adding your code it is now incrementing the month, like the image I have put in the Edit, so instead of incrementing `1` its incrementing and concatinating the month

Answer (score 0):

Just another potential solution, rather than your current system could you not potentially implement something like the following:

**Events** Table
@id, event_name, event_date

```
CREATE TABLE Events (
  `id` int,
  `event_name` varchar(64),
  `event_date` timestamp
);
```

Then you could get the amount of events per month with a query like so:

```
SELECT count(event_name) as event_count,
       MONTH(event_date) as month
FROM Events
WHERE MONTH(event_date) = 3
GROUP BY LEFT(event_date, 7);
```

So if we had this test data:

```
INSERT INTO Events (
  id, event_name, event_date
)
VALUES 
('1', 'Some Event', '2016-03-01'),
('2', 'Another Event', '2016-03-06'),
('3', 'Event Three', '2016-03-12'),
('4', 'Event Four', '2016-03-18'),
('5', 'Event Five', '2016-03-21')
```

The following would be returned by the query:

```
| event_count | month |
|-------------|-------|
|           5 |     3 |
```

You can find the [fiddle for it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdabeb/1)

That way on the PHP side if you wanted the number of events per month from your database you could do something like:

```
$month = 3;
$sql = "SELECT count(event_name) as event_count
        FROM Events
        WHERE MONTH(event_date) = '". mysql_real_escape_string($month) ."'
        GROUP BY LEFT(event_date, 7);";

$eventCount = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql), 0);
echo $eventCount; // Outputs 5
```

Not tested all of this, just a musing I had and I'm about to head home from work so it's a bit rushed towards the end, but hopefully another perspective may help somewhat.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will certainly take it into consideration when Im querying the total events